# JavaScript: push method to averaging arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, input, push

I'm attempting to get the userInput to push the data into the array but, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. When I run the program it comes back Answer is NaN. Am I calling the addtoList function wrong or is my logic wrong somewhere?

```js
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <title>Grade Average</title>
    <head>
        <script>
            
            var grades = ["0"];
            var total = 0;
            
            function addtoList()
            {
                var userInput = parseInt(txtBox1);
                grades.push(userInput);
            }
            
            function getAverage()
            {
            for (var i = 0; i < grades.length - 1; i++)
                {
                    total += total + grades;
                }
            if (grades.length > 0)
                {
                    alert("Average is " + (total / grades.length));
                }
            }
            
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text"
               id="txtBox1">
        <input type="button"
               id="Sumbit"
               value="Add to List"
               onclick="addtoList()">
        <input type="button"
               id="Calculate"
               value="Calculate"
               onclick="getAverage()">
               
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The value in Grades is a string, not a number. "0" = string. 0 = number.

Answer (score 2):

- txtBox1 should be defined as a variable.
- Grades starting value of `"0"` is a string and you cannot add/subtract/multiply/divide a string because it has no numeric value. Instead of: `"0"` a number value has no quotations: `0` - however in your code since you're calculating an average you can leave it blank unless you **want** 0 to be the first value.
- You can't get a value of an input box by referencing its `id`, you need to get that element using `document.querySelector(id)` and then point to its value by using the `value` method
- Your `total` value should be redeclared every time you recalculate the value. This means that it should be declared *within* the function that calculates the total.
- In your `for` loop you don't need to run it through to `grades.length -1` since you're using a `<` operator you can simply say `grades.length`. Also in the for loop you can't simply say `Grades` when trying to add the number because it's not a number, it's an `array`. The number/value is *inside* the array. You get its value by referencing the `index` value which you set as the `i` variable. In code this looks like `grades[i]`.
- As pointed out in the comments total can be calculated by saying `total += grades[i]` not `total += total + grades[i]` which adds total to total to the value at the index in grades.

```js
var grades = [];   
            var txtBox1 = document.querySelector("#txtBox1");
            function addtoList()
            {
                var userInput = parseInt(txtBox1.value);
                grades.push(userInput);
      
            }
            
            function getAverage()
            {
            var total = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
                {
                    total += grades[i];
                }
                console.log(total);
            if (grades.length > 0)
                {
                    alert("Average is " + (total / grades.length));
                }
            }
```

```html
<input type="text"
               id="txtBox1">
        <input type="button"
               id="Sumbit"
               value="Add to List"
               onclick="addtoList()">
        <input type="button"
               id="Calculate"
               value="Calculate"
               onclick="getAverage()">
```

Comment: There's still something wrong in your code snippet. For example, enter 15 and hit "add" several times, hit "calculate", hit "add" several times, "hit calculate" => the number is way too high!

Comment: @Connum one moment.

Comment: `total += total + grades[i];` is doing the adding twice.

Answer (score 0):

There are few changes which need to be done.See the comments.After showing average reset the length of the array and the `total`

```js
var grades = [];
var total = 0;

function addtoList() {
  //pass id of the input and use radix while using parseint
  var userInput = parseInt(document.getElementById('txtBox1').value, 10);
  grades.push(userInput);
  console.log(grades)
}

function getAverage() {
  //grades.length is not same as grades.length-1
  for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
    //using total+ will duplicate the value
    total = total + grades[i];
  }
  console.log(total)
  if (grades.length > 0) {
    alert("Average is " + (total / grades.length));
    grades.length = 0;
    total = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtBox1">
<input type="button" id="Sumbit" value="Add to List" onclick="addtoList()">
<input type="button" id="Calculate" value="Calculate" onclick="getAverage()">
```

Comment: Same problem here as with the other answer: Enter - for example - 15 and hit "add" several times, hit "calculate", hit "add" several times, "hit calculate" => the number is way too high!

Comment: @Connum have updated the answer hopefully it will work

Comment: Now the grades array is reset every time the calculation is triggered - I'm not sure that's intended by the OP

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple issues at play here:
First, you can initialize an empty `array` simple by opening/closing square brackets--no need to input a `string` or `number`: `var grades = [];`

Second, you *shouldn't* target DOM elements simply by writing their ID into Javascript code--they should be selected: `var userInput = parseInt(document.querySelector('#txtBox1').value);`

Third, `arrays` are all indexed starting from 0 and can be accessed using bracket notation like this: `grades[0]` -- with that in mind, when you're inside of your `for` loop, you're not actually pushing any specific `grade` value to your `total`, you're instead push the *entire array* each time. Try this: `total += grades[i];`

Finally, you want to ensure your DOM is loaded in before your Javascript so place your `<script>` tags at the bottom of your HTML. Instead of doing in-line events, I recommend you use event listeners inside your Javascript code to handle the Add to Total/Calculate buttons:

```
document.querySelector('#Submit').addEventListener('click', addtoList);
document.querySelector('#Calculate').addEventListener('click', getAverage);
```

As a stretch goal, I recommend you tap into one of those functions and find a way to reset your input box everytime the `addtoList` function is called--for the sake of user experience.

Hope this helps!

Comment: *"you cannot target DOM elements simply by writing their ID into Javascript code"* - actually, you *can*! That doesn't mean that you *should*, but elements with an ID are automatically available as globals on the window object.

Comment: Holy! I never knew that! Thank you!